# How to grep all files that have a keyword and files should be created today

Tags: grep, find

Have a directory with files. how to grep all files with a particular keyword and files should be created today.

tried this :

```
grep -r -n "pass" *.json
```

this gives the line number and only searches json file but how to add pipe to search for only files that are created today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `find` command as the source of the list of files to search.

```
grep -n "pass" $(find . -daystart -ctime 0 -name '*.json')
```

`-ctime` says "creation date should have been 0 days ago", and `-daystart` says to base it on the beginning of the day for "days ago", not "24 hours ago" ago.

Comment: got two files actually there are only one file - 1.json

Got these two

`1.json and ./1.json`

Comment: Those are the same file. I don't know how it is you're getting it twice.

Comment: created a new repo and tried but still getting them

Comment: Run `find . -daystart -ctime 0 -name '*.json'` on its own and see what you get.  You should only get the one json file.

Comment: yes got only one file ./1.json

Comment: when i tried this command `grep -r -n -w "pass" *.json $(find . -daystart -ctime 0 -name '*.json')` got two files

Comment: You have an extra '*.json' in there.

Comment: ohh got it .....